# How did this expression result in 3?

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

The below expression results in 3.

Could you please explain why the expression below results in 3 while (1 & 2) results in 0?

`(1 | 2) results 3 and (1 & 2) results 0`

Comment: The Oracle tutorial, [Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) should help you understand.

Comment: [Neither expression results in true](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/66367070/2). These are bitwise operators, not boolean operators. Integers don't have a boolean value in Java.

Answer (score 4):

These are bit-wise OR and bit-wise AND operators. The OR / AND operator is applied to each pair of bits of the input integers separately.

since (1 OR 0) == 1 and (0 OR 1) == 1:

```
1 | 2 is 01 OR
         10
         --
         11   == 3
```

since (1 AND 0) == 0 and (0 AND 1) == 0:

```
1 & 2 is 01 AND
         10
         --
         00   == 0
```